# Nested Generics in Java

Tags: java, generics

Let me, please, ask for an explanation.

Inside the method doit() I can intantiate the generic nested class `In<T>`

```
public class A {

  public static class In<T> {
  }

  public static <X> void doit() {
    new In<X>();
  }
}
```

I can, of course, also reach any members of the class `In<T>`

```
public class A {

  public static class In<T> {
    public static class Inner<U> {
    }
  }

  public static <X> void doit() {
    new In.Inner<X>();
  }
}
```

I can still reach members of the class `In<T>` from the method doit() when both class and method are nested inside another class Container

```
public class A {

  public static class Container {

    public static class In<T> {

      public static class Inner<U> {
      }
    }

    public static <X> void doit() {
      new In.Inner<X>();
    }
  }
}
```

However, making A generic, as in

```
public class A<V> {

  public static class Container {

    public static class In<T> {

      public static class Inner<U> {
      }
    }

    public static <X> void doit() {
      new In.Inner<X>();
    }
  }
}
```

the compiler excepts an error: "The member type A.Container.In must be parameterized, since it is qualified with a parameterized type"

Could you, please, give me an explanation?

Notice that in the previous code classes and method are static.

Notice also that making generic the class Container, as in

```
public class A<V> {

  public static class Container<Z> {

    public static class In<T> {

      public static class Inner<U> {
      }
    }

    public static <X> void doit() {
      new In.Inner<X>();
    }
  }
}
```

The code compiles.

And compiles also the following code where Container is no longer generic but the call of the constructor of the class `Inner<U>` is now the more qualified `Container.In.Inner<X>()`

```
public class A<V> {

  public static class Container {

    public static class In<T> {

      public static class Inner<U> {
      }
    }

    public static <X> void doit() {
      new Container.In.Inner<X>();
    }
  }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Seems like a problem of Eclipse (at least for me)... I was able to compile the problematic code from command line via `javac` just fine.

Comment: Thank you @Pavel, I was just wondering whether something was wrong in my knowledge of Java.

Comment: I have to add that I spent some time going through Eclipse Bugzilla and did not find anything there. You should try it with newest Eclipse build and report bug if it does not work.

Comment: As @Pavel suggests, the bug should be reported. My Eclipse build, however, is quite old and I am very busy at moment to think to upgrade it. So, please, let me encourage anyone to report the bug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A nested class, being a `static` member of a class, does not depend on the (instance) type parameter of the class. As such, in your example

```
class A<V> {

    public static class Container {

        public static class In<T> {

            public static class Inner<U> {
            }
        }

        public static <X> void doit() {
            new In.Inner<X>(); // compilation error
        }
    }
}
```

There is absolutely no reason that the class instance creation expression

```
new In.Inner<X>()
```

would cause the error

> "The member type `A.Container.In` must be parameterized, since it is
>   qualified with a parameterized type"

The `Inner` member type is a nested class of `In`, which is a nested  class of `Container`, which is a nested class of `A`. None of them have any relation to the type parameter declared in their declaring class.

This seems like a bug in your IDE and I would report it as such.

Comment: I definitively agree @Sotirios, as also Pavel suggested the javac compiler is not affected. My Java IDE is Eclipse Version: 3.6.2 Build id: M20110210-1200.

Comment: Created bug report - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=433989 . @rvend you should accept this answer and go with the workaround of using `Container.In.Inner<X>()` if you face this issue in a real project.